# row number partition doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a problem. Don't know why.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.rmid, c.nama ORDER BY a.tanggalrekam) rn,
       a.rmid, a.psid, c.nama, a.tanggalrekam
from _tRekamMedis a
inner join _tRekamMedisTindakan b on a.rmid= b.rmid
inner join _tPasien c on a.psid = c.psid
inner join _tSecurityUser d on b.dokterid = d.securityuserid
inner join _tTindakan e on b.tindakanid = e.tindakanid
```

result:

```
    rn  rmid    psid    nama        tanggalrekam    dokterid
    1   1       1       Fauzan      2017-06-20      -2147483648
    2   1       1       Fauzan      2017-06-20      -2147483648
    3   1       1       Fauzan      2017-06-20      -2147483648
    1   2       2       Huri        2017-06-20      -2147483648
```

It should be:

```
    rn  rmid    psid    nama        tanggalrekam    dokterid
    1   1       1       Fauzan      2017-06-20      -2147483648
    1   1       1       Fauzan      2017-06-20      -2147483648
    1   1       1       Fauzan      2017-06-20      -2147483648
    2   2       2       Huri        2017-06-20      -2147483648
```

the `rownumber` doesn't work. It shows on `rn` field. Anyone can help?

Comment: Try it with `Rank()` like this `select              Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a.rmid, c.nama ORDER BY a.tanggalrekam) rn,
                        a.rmid, a.psid, c.nama, a.tanggalrekam .....`

Comment: It does work, this is what `row_number` does: it enumerates records within the same partition. Here you have two partitions of `rmid, nama`. The first one contains three records, hence `rn = 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: You can use row_number, dense_rank, rank functions as per your need. They are almost similar but differ in peculiar manner. Perhaps thats the thing you might want to review.

Comment: Also Include psid in partition

Comment: @B House: Why? Why do you think, when looking at the desired result, that Haminteu wants a partition? Why do you think this partition should include `psid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously don't want numbers per a.rmid, c.nama, so remove the `PARTITION BY` clause altogether. You are simply looking for `DENSE_RANK` without any partition:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.rmid, c.nama a.tanggalrekam) AS rn,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Include all columns for partition

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.rmid, a.psid,c.nama,a.tanggalrekam ORDER BY a.tanggalrekam) rn,
       a.rmid, a.psid, c.nama, a.tanggalrekam
from _tRekamMedis a
inner join _tRekamMedisTindakan b on a.rmid= b.rmid
inner join _tPasien c on a.psid = c.psid
inner join _tSecurityUser d on b.dokterid = d.securityuserid
inner join _tTindakan e on b.tindakanid = e.tindakanid
```

Comment: Since the first 3 rows have identical values in all (non-ROW_NUMBER() based) columns, how do you think partitioning by all of them will allow all 3 rows to be numbered `1` within their partition?

Comment: Your right guys, shoudl be dense or use cte just to get one row